# What exactly is radius of convergence?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

This is probably a very basis question for people, but I am having a hard time on picturing the radius of convergence. Here's my current understanding:

So let say I have a sequence $f_n$ and the sequence converges to $f$. Then the radius of convergence is a ball around $f$, and the space within the ball is packed (or made) with $f_n$ that converges to $f$? In addition, the radius of convergence only exist for *uniformly convergent* because otherwise it will not form a ball?

Am I right? If so, what about series, is there any different between sequnce and series?

Comment: The radius of convergence is defined usually for a power series and it seems that you are not referring to any power series. Can you write down the definition of radius of convergence?

Comment: The ball is not around $f$. It's around a value around which $f_n$, the power series, is generated.